# NodeJS http server, pending requests block the server

Tags: node.js, http

I was experimenting and im facing a limitation i can't understand.
This is what i am trying to achieve:

A user request a route where the output can take ~10 sec to calculate.
Some other concurrent requests may trigger the exact same route. To avoid running the calculation for each of them, i store all these requests into an array.
Once the calculation started at 1st is done, the output of it is sent into the responses of all the stored requests.

This snippet doesn't works as expected:

- A 1st request would fork a child process and run a calculation for 10s before responding. It works like expected.
- A 2nd request, sent let's say 2 seconds after the first, would see it's response stored then ended by the child process once it ends it's calculation. It works like expected.
- A 3rd request is sent 2 seconds after the 2nd request. The child process is still calculating. But this is where it fails. Rather than storing the response for later, the execution pause right before the "console.log("Incoming request");" until request 1 and 2 finish their things.

I really can't understand what is happening.
It's like the server is blocked until the 2 pending requests get ended.
But i can't believe NodeJS concurrent connections are limited to 2.

*test.js*

```
const { fork }      = require("child_process");
const http          = require('http');

var store = [];

http.createServer((request, response) => {    

    console.log("Incoming request");
  
    if(store.length === 0){ // First request

        store.push(response);  

        let child = fork( __dirname+'/fork.js');

        child.on('message', (message) => {                       
        
            if( message === "over" ){             
       
                store.forEach( (response) =>{

                    response.end(message);
                });     

                store = [];
            }
        });

        child.send('start');  
    }
    else{ // Child process is already calculating
    
        store.push(response);    
    }              

}).listen(8181, () => {

 console.log('server running');
});
```

*fork.js*

```
const child = require('child_process');

process.on('message', (message) => {

    // Send a shell cmd that sleeps for 10 seconds
    child.exec('sleep 10', 

        (error, stdout, stderr) => {

            process.send("over");               
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: How exactly are you making the test requests?

Comment: By opening 3 different chrome tabs.

Comment: Browsers typically limit the number of connections to a single host. I ran a test with a Node.js script that starts 10 requests, and they work as expected: https://gist.github.com/robertklep/f9c9ae0e1ef4809df7674287f288273f

Comment: Oh browser limitations ... It didn't come to my mind, thanks a lot @robertklep !

Answer (score 0):

Earlier versions of node.js had an imposed limit of 5 simultaneous connections, precisely v0.10 or earlier. What is the application server specification that you are running the code, that is memory, CPU core?

https://tpiros.dev/blog/concurrent-http-connections-in-node-js/

Comment: Yes, i read about this limitations also. Im currently running node v12, 2 vcpu, 4Go ram.
My issue was coming from Chrome limiting the amount of opened requests when they are similar (same host/same route). On my machine i can't have more than 2 similar opened requests.